# How do I store this in Redis?

Tags: database, model, schema, redis

I have many products (product_id). Users (user_id) view the products.

I want to **query which users viewed whatever product in the last 24 hours**.  (In other words, I want to keep a list of user_ids attached to that product_id...and when 24 hours is up for a user, that user pops off that list and the record disappears)

How do I store this in Redis? Can someone give me a high-level schema because I'm new in Redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something similar I use a sorted set with values being user ids and score being the current time. When updating the set, remove older items with ZREMRANGEBYSCORE as well as updating the time score for the current user.

Update with code:

Whenever a new item is added:

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE recentitems 0 [DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10).Ticks]
ZADD recentitems [DateTime.Now.Ticks] [item.id]
```

To get the ids of items added in the last 10 minutes:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE recentitems [DateTime.Now.Ticks] [DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10).Ticks]
```

Note that you could also use

```
ZREVRANGE recentitems 0 -1
```

if you don't mind that the set could include older items if nothing has been added recently.

That gets you a list of item ids. You then use GET/MGET/HGET/HMGET as appropriate to retrieve the actual items for display.

Comment: Can you explain more about how this works? I'm confused.  What would the sorted set contain?

Answer (score 2):

If you want redis keys to drop off automatically then you'll probably want to use a redis key for every user_id-to-product_id map. So, you would write by doing something like `redis.set "user-to-products:user_id:product_id", timestamp` followed by `redis.expire "user-to-products:user_id:product_id" 86400` (24hrs, in seconds).

To retrieve the current list you should be able to do `redis.keys "user-to-products:user_id:*"`

Comment: Is this a scalable way to do it? How fast are the lookups with * ?

Comment: It's a hash table lookup, so it should be fast, but isn't 100% ideal. There is more information about [key pattern lookups](http://redis.io/commands/keys) on the redis website. For something truly scalable, you shoudl go with Tom Clarkson's answer.

Comment: Just wanted to add, if you want the best of both worlds you can use EXPIRE to set a 24hr clock on your Sorted Set, then users who don't visit for more than 24 hours are automatically pruned from the database and you only have to ZREMRANGEBYSCORE on keys that still exist (your active users).

Comment: Can you explain more about the sorted-set method?  What would be inside the sorted set? Why would i need EXPIRE if I'm doing a ZREMRANGEBYSCORE?

Comment: I don't think expiring the sorted set would work that way - it would only be able to delete the entire set as expiry is applied to the key containing the set rather than members of the set.

Comment: You don't need to use EXPIRE if you are using ZREMRANGEBYSCORE. However, you might want to. Using EXPIRE you can have redis automatically remove the entire Sorted Set whenever the *newest* product has expired. This would save you the effort or writing a background task to clean up Sorted Sets left behind when a customer leaves and doesn't come back.

Comment: This not a scalable way.  From [redis website] (http://redis.io/commands/keys): "Don't use KEYS in your regular application code." and "Consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care."